# How to make a js code which allows user to view their page only if they satisfy the 'if' condition?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

This is the sample code:

```
var users = ["ownersName","Others"];
var name=prompt("Enter your name");
if(name==users[0]){
    w
    alert("Hey"+' '+name)
    alert("You have been granted the webMaster Role!")
}
else{
    console.log("hello user");
}
```

I want to allow the user to view the page only if his name satisfies 'ownersName'.

Comment: More context please. If this is a basic exercise, fine. If you want to put this anywhere on the web. Don't! This is about as secure as a `Do not enter` sign on an wide open door.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redirect to blank URL `about:blank` or

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML='';
```

to restrict the user to view page

```js
var users = ["ownersName","Others"];
var name=prompt("Enter your name");
if(name==users[0]){
    w
    alert("Hey"+' '+name)
    alert("You have been granted the webMaster Role!")
}
else{
   document.documentElement.innerHTML = '';
   //window.location = 'about:blank';
}
```